# What is the purpose of the scripts section in package.json?

Tags: node.js, package.json

What is the scripts section inside package.json?

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "start-me" : "node one.js",
   "start-over" : "node two.js"
```

}

What does `start-me` and `start-over` mean here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'scripts' section can be used by the `npm` or `yarn` commands to allow you to do the following; `npm run start-me` at which point it will execute `node one.js`

Comment: I could directly run `node one.js`. Is there any specific use?

Comment: Of course , scripts section is only an alias to do one or more command, is more an abstraction to final user of your user, example: your test commands are long ugly and with few flags but you easy create the script npm test and your final user don't see the ugly command, understand now?